# empty HTACCESS drops webpage (403 error)

Tags: .htaccess, php, conf.d

I know there are a few of (probably) the same questions out there, but I just can't find any working solution.

I've placed the .htaccess file next to my index.php on the server.
And even if the .htaccess is empty the site returns error 403 (forbidden access).

What I wanted to do is remove the .php extension.

```
http://foo.net/web_new/index_1024.php
```

And even if I put the following into the .htaccess, the website still returns error 403.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

I've found on the web, to enable the mod_rewrite, I should enable it in `httpd.conf`. But I search the whole server (ftp), but there is no clue.

where phpinfo() finds conf.d file

```
/etc/php5/conf.d
```

where is my root

```
/srv/www/web6/
```

Any idea, what could i do?

Comment: If you remove the .htaccess and just have a normal index.html page in your web folder does it 403?

Comment: Do you have any other sites under that web root?

Comment: I guess you rented your webspace and do not actually own the server? Are you able to change into the /etc/php5/conf.d folder from your FTP client? Do you have SSH access? If not, then there's no way for you to change the httpd.conf file, you will have to ask the server owner/your provider.

Comment: If i remove .htaccess file, the site works as it should :). There are no any other sites in the web_new folder. Yes the server is rented. And the deepest i can get on the server is srv/www/web6

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that `.htaccess` has 644 permissions
2. I think you can remove that `ifModule`... I find it "messy" there...
3. Your code looks well...

Comment: Alex, thank you for your answer. .htaccess permissions are already set to 644, and I also removed <ifModule..., but the error is still there

Comment: check if you enabled mod_rewrite stuff... you have to uncomment something or add some lines somewhere...